# Remove digits and the last space if exist from a string

Tags: haskell, recursion

The function shall aim to remove all digits and the last space if exist, for example if the input is `"My Number is 123"` output shall be `"My Number is"` so far I am stuck at how to remove the last space, in my solution the output would be `"My Number is "` How can I solve this?

```
deleteDigits :: String -> String
deleteDigits [] = []
deleteDigits (c:cs) | isDigit(c) = deleteDigits cs
                    | otherwise = c : deleteDigits cs
```

Comment: I suggest writing two functions, `deleteDigits` and `deleteLastSpace`, separately. Then write the main function `deleteDigitsAndLastSpace` as a composition of the two.

Comment: `deleteLastSpace` should be relatively easy, especially if you think about the base cases first.

Comment: What about two or more spaces infront of the last digit?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann very good spot! I need to consider this as well

Answer (score 0):

As I'm guessing (probably wrong) that you only can use one function to make this, you can use the `words` and `unwords`from *Data.List*. This way you would make your whole *String* into *[String]* made up of each word, then remove the last one, and convert it back to a *String* like this:

```
deleteDigits :: String -> String
deleteDigits = unwords.init.words
```

I'm not sure if you want to make so it removes all the digits from *String*, making "My2323 number is 123" into "My number is", but I'm guessing that's not the case.

Comment: You appear to be asking for clarification on the question. This is best suited for comments. Once that clarity is present, a suitable answer may be written.

Comment: @Chris Sorry because I just started, but one question, when something like this happens what I'm suposed to do? I mean I think I found a solution for what he strikly asked but I found some exceptions that he was not asking about. Sorry for my ignorance since, like I just said I'm really new to all of this. Thank you!

Comment: Leave a comment requesting clarification, if your current reputation permits.